# Múltiplos bancos de dados com Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

Na minha aplicação, os clientes tem seus próprios banco de dados e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação REST, com Spring Boot, do qual preciso configurar os DataSources para conectar com os bancos de dados, de acordo com um PathParam da URL, em runtime.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Pesquisei sobre AbstractRoutingDataSource e Multi-Tenant, mas não consegui entender o funcionamento muito bem.

Se alguém puder me ajudar... nem que seja para me dar um norte hehe, para eu poder implementar tudo isso corretamente :)

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Lhe sugiro a leitura do artigo [deste blog](https://tassioauad.com/2018/04/03/configurando-multiplos-bancos-de-dados-no-spring-boot/) que exemplifica a configuração de para aplicação spring-boot para trabalhar com dois bancos de dados.

Em resumo, esta seria a sequência de atividades a serem realizadas:

1. Configurar os dados de conexão dos dois bancos no `application.properties`;
2. Criar as classes de entidade e de repositório para cada banco de dados; e
3. Criar uma classe de configuração para cada banco de dados (tirar um pouco da automação do Spring Boot, para termos mais controle do que está acontecendo e, consequentemente, podermos informar cada pacote ligado a cada BD).

O autor ainda, salienta que ao final é necessário anotar os métodos de pelo menos uma das classes de configuração com a *annotation* `@Primary`, para informar que este é o banco primário ou principal da aplicação.

Comment: Diego, muito obrigado por responder. Mas, nesse caso que vc descreveu, eu teria os bancos de dados já pré-definidos, certo? Porém, no caso real da minha aplicação, cada cliente tem seu próprio banco de dados, ou seja, caso eu cadastre um novo cliente, um BD será gerado para ele também. Daí, o carregamento desses dados teria que ser de forma de dinâmica

Comment: @PauloAugusto - Acho que entendi o que você precisa. Olha esse vídeo que fala sobrea Implementação de Multitenancy por schema com Hibernate, da Algaworks: [link](https://youtu.be/AUcwQcgIahU)

Answer (score 0):

Caso você deseje criar um novo Datasource em tempo de execução, você pode utilizar o [DataSourceBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.html).

Esta classe provê uma flexibilidade e uma facilidade enorme, um exemplo de utilização é o seguinte:

```
public DataSource buildDatasource(String url, String username, String password) {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url).username(username).password(password).build();
}
```

Apenas lembre-se de que você precisa ter os drivers para os bancos em que deseja conectar disponíveis em sua aplicação ou servidor, caso tenha curiosidade em saber como funciona basta olhar o [source code da classe](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.java)